# pgfplots: stacking 'fill between' over filled curve

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I have a set of filled-plots (MWE: red) and line-plots (MWE: blue) in a graph. Stacking order works fine according to the order of code lines. Additionally, I need to fill the area between two line-plots **in front of** the filled plot.

The *fill between* works fine, but only visible **behind** the filled-plot although drawn after the filled-plot.

(a) Is this a bug or a feature?

(b) How can I force the *fill between* to be visible on top?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot [draw = none, fill=red]
            % \addplot [draw = none, fill=red, opacity=0.5]
                table[row sep=crcr]{%
                    1   1\\
                    1   2\\
                    2   2\\
                    2   1\\
                    }
                --cycle;
            \addplot [blue, name path = A]
                table[row sep=crcr]{%
                    1.4 1.2\\
                    1.2 1.4\\
            };
            \addplot [blue, name path = B]
                table[row sep=crcr]{%
                    1.8 1.6\\
                    1.6 1.8\\
            };
            \addplot[fill=green]
                fill between[ of = A and B ];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result according to MWE:
[image: MWE no opacity]

Result with opacity to show correct *fill between* behind the filled plot:
[image: MWE with opacity]

Comment: on behalf of all color blinds, you, sir, are mean :)

Comment: sorry for that one @percusse, users are free to choose colors of their liking... for their solution posts, of course ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To question (a):
This is a *feature* and in the following solution you will find out why.

To question (b):
If you just want everything to appear as per given order you could simply add `fill between/on layer={main}` to the axis options, as in my presented solution below.

The downside of doing this is, that then your "fill" will partly cover the "draw"s. Please zoom on one of the lines as proof. But that *normally* is an undesired behavior and the reason why the `fill between` stuff is by default drawn on the "lower level" `pre main`.

Thus [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417389/95441) suggests the right approach to show everything "as desired", i.e. moving either the "red" stuff further back (`on layer=pre main` technically would have been enough) or move the "blue" stuff more to the front, e.g. add `on layer=axis descriptions` or higher with `/pgfplots/layers/standard` layers.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        fill between/on layer={main},
    ]
        \addplot [draw = none, fill=red!25]
        % \addplot [draw = none, fill=red, opacity=0.5]
            table {
                1   1
                1   2
                2   2
                2   1
                }
            -- cycle;
        \addplot [blue,ultra thick,name path = A]
            table {
                1.4 1.2
                1.2 1.4
        };
        \addplot [blue,ultra thick, name path = B]
            table {
                1.8 1.6
                1.6 1.8
        };
        \addplot [fill=green!25] fill between[ of = A and B ];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: thx for the explanation to (b), understood. In addition, your approach `fill between/on layer={main}` enables a workaround with invisible lines for `fill between` and redrawing the lines afterwards. Maybe _bad coding style_ but avoids considering layers, which might be beneficial in more complex graphs/pictures.

Comment: Am I right that this is just a comment of yours and that there is no question? Because I am not sure if I have understood everything right.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, no more questions. It was just a _comment_ how your solution/information could potentially be (ab)used to avoid multiple layers and still draw correct `fill between`s.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to put the plots on different layers.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot [draw = none, fill=red,on layer=axis background]
            % \addplot [draw = none, fill=red, opacity=0.5]
                table[row sep=crcr]{%
                    1   1\\
                    1   2\\
                    2   2\\
                    2   1\\
                    }
                --cycle;
            \addplot [blue, name path = A]
                table[row sep=crcr]{%
                    1.4 1.2\\
                    1.2 1.4\\
            };
            \addplot [blue, name path = B]
                table[row sep=crcr]{%
                    1.8 1.6\\
                    1.6 1.8\\
            };
            \addplot[fill=green]
                fill between[ of = A and B ];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thx @marmot, that's an option I've looked into, but since the real case involves larger sets of filled and already stacked plots I was wondering if there is another approach. From my point of view, your answer is more like a manual overide, working fine nonetheless. Any idea about question part (a): bug or feature?

Comment: @hanshansen I can't tell whether this is a bug or feature, all I know is that pgfplot delays the expansion of the plot commands such that your problem arises. On the other hand, this strategy seems to be the only one that allows pgfplots to adjust the plot range etc. Notice that in section 4.27 of the manual there is a long discussion of layers, and you could define your own set which can have as many layers as plots (if I understand the manual correctly).

Comment: I'll wait a little more, maybe someone comes up with another idea/information. If not, I'll grant you the accepted answer...